# Apache HttpClient4 + OpenJDK11 different behavior on CentOS Linux and Windows with SSL websites

Tags: linux, ssl-certificate, apache-httpclient-4.x, java-security, cacerts

A Java crawler developed on **Apache HttpClient** works fine on Windows, but throws **"Algorithm constraints check failed on signature algorithm: SHA1withRSA"** on Linux when crawling sites having certificate signed by Certum. Both ran on the latest openjdk-11. `java.security` on both OSes are compared and properties like `jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms` and `jdk.security.legacyAlgorithms` are the same. I even tried to comment all these properties on the Linux, no no success. Linux ca-certs are up to date and Certum is also trusted on java keystore there. Tools like `curl` and `wget` can safely download these https sites.

When `running openssl s_client -showcerts -connect`, it shows that root certum ca certificate uses RSA-SHA1 on these sites:

```
 3 s:C = PL, O = Unizeto Sp. z o.o., CN = Certum CA
   i:C = PL, O = Unizeto Sp. z o.o., CN = Certum CA
   a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 2048 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA1
   v:NotBefore: Jun 11 10:46:39 2002 GMT; NotAfter: Jun 11 10:46:39 2027 GMT
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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```

OpenJDK version on Linux:

```
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Red_Hat-11.0.17.0.8-2.el9) (build 11.0.17+8-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Red_Hat-11.0.17.0.8-2.el9) (build 11.0.17+8-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Here is the exception trace:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Certificates do not conform to algorithm constraints
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:353)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:296)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:291)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:654)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:473)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:369)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:443)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:421)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:183)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1506)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1416)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:456)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:427)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:436)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:384)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
        at myproject.Crawler.load(Crawler.java:127)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Certificates do not conform to algorithm constraints
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkAlgorithmConstraints(SSLContextImpl.java:1681)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkAdditionalTrust(SSLContextImpl.java:1606)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted(SSLContextImpl.java:1550)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:638)
        ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Algorithm constraints check failed on signature algorithm: SHA1withRSA
        at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.AlgorithmChecker.check(AlgorithmChecker.java:237)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkAlgorithmConstraints(SSLContextImpl.java:1677)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that CentOS stream 9 overrides Java security policies on `/usr/share/crypto-policies/DEFAULT/java.txt` (accessible from `/etc/crypto-policies/back-ends`). Replaced JDK default jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms in the file resolved the issue!